# avconv -metadata doesn't work

Tags: avconv

I try following:

```
avconv -i ~/Downloads/test.mp4 -metadata key=val -c copy output.mp4  -y
roroco@roroco /tmp/avconv $ avconv -i output.mp4
```

the doesn't find the metadata "key" in output, the full output is [here](https://gist.github.com/roroco/87d48d0c48142df9d344afc40f52f334)

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution: the "key" is not metadata key, full keys is [here](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=FFmpeg_Metadata#QuickTime.2FMOV.2FMP4.2FM4A.2Fet_al.)